# Como poner en una lista , sublistas de un json

Tags: json, vb.net, lista

Hola estoy aprendiendo a usar lista de objetos y lo que pasa es que en el json tengo una sublista que no me carga los datos , les paso como es el json

```
  "id_recurso": 24493,
  "id_tipo_recurso": 2,
  "tipo_recurso": "PERSONA",
  "id_subtipo_recurso": 12,
  "subtipo_recurso": "TODO CONSTRUCCION",
  "identificacion": "20-3467916-1",
  "recurso": "ABAD, PEREZ GODOY",
  "id_contratista": 1172,
  "contratista": "LA OPTICA PEREZ",
  "habilitado_acceso": false,
  "acceso_hasta": "2022-05-22",
  "habilitaciones": {
    "3": {
      "id_habilitacion": 3,
      "habilitacion": "CONDUCE",
      "habilitado": true,
      "vencimiento": "2023-09-27"
    }
  }
}
```

La lista me lee id_recurso, tipo , subtipo , pero cuando entra en este sector no carga la sublista

```
    "3": {
      "id_habilitacion": 3,
      "habilitacion": "CONDUCE",
      "habilitado": true,
      "vencimiento": "2023-09-27"
    }
  }
}
```

Esta es la lista que tengo

```
Public Class data
    Public Property Id_Recurso As Integer
    Public Property Id_Tipo_Recurso As Integer
    Public Property Tipo_Recurso As String
    Public Property Id_Subtipo_Recurso As Integer
    Public Property Subtipo_Recurso As String
    Public Property Identificacion As String
    Public Property Recurso As String
    Public Property Id_Contratista As Integer
    Public Property Contratista As String
    Public Property Habilitado_Acceso As Boolean
    Public Property Acceso_Hasta As Date
    Public Property Numero As Integer

    Public Property Habilitaciones As habilitacion
End Class
```

Estoy en vb.net por si acaso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver, la propiedad `Public Property Habilitaciones As habilitacion`
deberia ser un diccionario para que te lo deserialize correctamente, en concreto:

```
Public Property Habilitaciones Dictionary(Of String, claseHabilitacion)
```

y en la subclase claseHabilitacion

```
Public Class claseHabilitacion
    Public Property IdHabilitacion As Integer
    Public Property Habilitacion As String
    Public Property Habilitado As Boolean
    Public Property Vencimiento As String
End Class
```

Comment: Me funciono , y te hago otra consulta @J.Salas, en el caso de que tenga dos idrecursos un ejemplo que termine igual pero despues del ultimo } tiene una coma , porque lo probe y me tira error en la coma , ejemplo `"vencimiento": "2023-09-27  }}},{Idrecurso.....`

Comment: Deberias deserializar a una Lista List (Of objetoRaiz)

Comment: Como seria en este caso ?

Answer (score 0):

El sub ítem `"3"` no tiene nombre. Debe tener un nombre y el número no debe tener comillas ni coma.

```
"habilitaciones": {
     3 {
      "id_habilitacion": 3,
      "habilitacion": "CONDUCE",
      "habilitado": true,
      "vencimiento": "2023-09-27"
    }
  }
```

Comment: El tema que no lo puedo modificar , viene así default , como lo podria hacer ? , por que hay varios que tienen varias habilitaciones con diferente numero , pero los campos de adentro son los mismos

Comment: Modifique la respuesta. Si el número está sin comillas, es una ID